# Props change when I setState in my component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props, react-state

I got a problem with my nextJs Application.

I have actually a page where I have an edit value initialized at false and render a component Informations,

```
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);

  function getEditStatus() {
    if (!edit) {
      return <MaterialInfo edit={edit} setEdit={setEdit} material={material} />;
    } else {
      return <EditMaterial edit={edit} setEdit={setEdit} material={material} />;
    }
  }
  return <div> {getEditStatus()} </div>;
```

When I press the edit button, my state go to true and render the edit component. I give my data in props, and in my edit component I initialize a state with my data inside.

Now, in my edit component I have the input with my information, I can change informations.

```
const [properties, setProperties] = useState(material.properties);
  const [fournisseur, setFournisseur] = useState(material.fournisseur);

  function changeCharacteristique(nom, e) {
    const allProperties = [...properties];
    const index = allProperties.findIndex((item) => item.id_nom.nom === nom);

    allProperties[index].id_nom.nom = e;
    setProperties(allProperties);
  }

  const listProperties = material.properties.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) =>
              changeCharacteristique(item.id_nom.nom, e.target.value)
            }
            value={item.id_nom.nom}
          />
        </td>
        <td>{item.valeur}</td>
        <td>{item.unite}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
```

My problem here is when I confirm the edit, I go in my Informations component, but keep my change for my array in my data but not for my text. For me the information component should not keep my edit data because I just setState in my component and I never change my initial data.

This is problematic if I want to do a cancel button because my data is changing anyway.

Cancel edit

[image]

Keep data

[image]

I did a little sandBox to show my problem

You can see the problem here, https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-herschel-6dn0i?file=/components/EditMaterial.js

Comment: figured out and updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Though I cannot explain why your update method doesn't work.

I've changed your function to how I normally do and now it should work.

```
  const changeCharacteristique = (nom, e) => {
    // const allProperties = [...properties];
    // const index = allProperties.findIndex((item) => item.id_nom.nom === nom);

    // allProperties[index].id_nom.nom = e;
    setProperties(
      properties.map((item) =>
        item.id_nom.nom === nom ? { ...item, id_nom: { nom: e } } : item
      )
    );
  };

  //should be properties.map not material.properties.map
  const listProperties = properties.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) =>
              changeCharacteristique(item.id_nom.nom, e.target.value)
            }
            value={item.id_nom.nom}
          />
        </td>
        <td>{item.valeur}</td>
        <td>{item.unite}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
```

Comment: Yeah thx it's working, but I still don't understand why this problem happen. Is this because a state mutation happen? But it's not possible because I do a copy of my array. It's really strange.

Comment: It's strange yes, I don't understand either. Sorry I couldn't help with the explanation.